# Spring Boot + Quartz: "Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I've implemented a scheduler routine in my Spring Boot application with Quartz Scheduler following this tutorial ([spring-boot-quartz-demo](https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo)) and did some modifications serving my purposes.

For example, my job service have to be able to list all objects in database and its children too, setting new values and finally update. All of this have to be transactional.

For some reason, the MyJob class doesn't allow to declare transactional methods in it, so I resolved this by injecting a new service class with transacitional method.

The job is working perfectly, but every time I run the application, it give me some warn messages:

```
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBean': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
[main] WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testJobBeanTrigger': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

*I reduced warn messages putting this:* `@DependsOn("testJobBean")`

I noticed that autowiring service in job class is causing it, but why? What I have to do to get rid of this warn messages?

Solutions of how to be able to declare `@Transacional` methods in job class are welcome!

**QuartzConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "quartz.enabled")
public class QuartzConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    List<Trigger> triggers;

    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(JobFactory jobFactory) throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());

        if (triggers != null && !triggers.isEmpty()) {
            factory.setTriggers(((Trigger[]) triggers.toArray(new Trigger[triggers.size()])));
        }

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    public static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression) {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    public static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class<?> jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

**AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java**

```
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

**MyJob.java**

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private TestService service;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        service.execute();
    }

    @Bean(name = "testJobBean")
    public JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail() {
        return QuartzConfig.createJobDetail(this.getClass());
    }

    @DependsOn("testJobBean")
    @Bean(name = "testJobBeanTrigger")
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(@Qualifier("testJobBean") JobDetail jobDetail,
            @Value("${quartz.job.test.cronExpression}") String cronExpression) {
        return QuartzConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail, cronExpression);
    }

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {

    private TestRepository testRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(TestRepository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public void execute() {
        log.debug("Job has been started");
        List<TestObject> list = testRepository.findAll();
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {

            System.out.println("\n");
            list.forEach(obj -> {
                System.out.println(
                        "TestObject ID: " + obj.getId() + "\n" + 
                        "SubTestObjects IDs: " + (obj.getSubTestObjects() == null ? "null" : obj.getSubTestObjects().toString()) + 
                        "AnotherSubTestObjects IDs: " + (obj.getAnotherSubTestObjects() == null ? "null" : obj.getAnotherSubTestObjects().toString())
                        );
            });
            System.out.println();

            log.info(list.size() + " test objects found");
        } else {
            log.info("No test objects were found");
        }
        log.debug("Job has been finished");
    }

}
```

**quartz.properties**

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval 3600000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem might be in the `createJobDetail` method, consider the below snippet:

```
    @Bean(name = "testJobBean")
    public JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail() {
        return QuartzConfig.createJobDetail(this.getClass());
    }

    @DependsOn("testJobBean")
    @Bean(name = "testJobBeanTrigger")
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(@Qualifier("testJobBean") JobDetail jobDetail,
            @Value("${quartz.job.test.cronExpression}") String cronExpression) {
        return QuartzConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail, cronExpression);
    }
```

It uses `this` in it's implementation which holds reference to current object. However, current object might also be in creation at that time, resulting in this error. I would recomment moving these 2 to `Config` class.

Also, use of `@DependsOn` is not a good practice.

Comment: You're right, moving these two bean creation methods would resolve that problem, but I did it on purpose because I wanted to isolate my jobs from configuration.